# How can I register a function returning a base64Binary element?

Tags: python, simplexmlrpcserver, pysimplesoap

I need to return a `base64Binary` to the client application, and I could only return "str" and "int" in "returns" parameter of "register_function" function.

I tried:

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

dispatcher = .....

base64Binary = base64.b64encode
dispatcher.register_function('fala', speech, args={'frase': str}, returns={'mp3': base64Binary})
```

and I get:

```
TypeError: unknonw type <function b64encode at 0x7f15a93c4dc0> for marshalling
```

I need produce the `xsd:base64Binary` type in the resulting `xml`.

Comment: can you cast it to a `str`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: shouldn't it be `base64Binary = base64.b64encode(STRING)`???

Answer (score 0):

```
import base64
 
byt = b'poppppo'
 
base64Binary = base64.b64encode(byt).decode("utf-8")

print(base64Binary, type(base64Binary))
```

out :

```
cG9wcHBwbw== <class 'str'>
```

and :

```
from io import StringIO
import base64

bas = StringIO('cG9wb3BvcG9wb3BvcG9wb3BvcG9wb2xvbG9sb2xv')

print(bas , type(bas))

print(bas.read() , type(bas.read()))



base64Binary = base64.b64decode('cG9wb3BvcG9wb3BvcG9wb3BvcG9wb2xvbG9sb2xv').decode('utf-8)')

print(base64Binary, type(base64Binary))

bas.seek(0)

base64Binary = base64.b64decode(bas.read()).decode('utf-8')

print(base64Binary, type(base64Binary))
```

out :

```
<_io.StringIO object at 0x7a07b3d61090> <class '_io.StringIO'>
cG9wb3BvcG9wb3BvcG9wb3BvcG9wb2xvbG9sb2xv <class 'str'>
popopopopopopopopopopololololo <class 'str'>
popopopopopopopopopopololololo <class 'str'>
>
```